# hint to approach this question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamic-programming

2 teams play in total
During the course of the game, each team gets points, and thus increases its score by 1.
The initial score is 0 for both teams.
The game ends when

One of the teams gets 25 points and another team has < 24 points ( strictly less than 24).
If the score ties at 24:24, the teams continue to play until the absolute difference between the scores is 2.
Given the final score of two teams game in the format A:B, can you print the number of different sequences of getting points by teams that leads to this final score?

Input Format
The first line contains A and the second line contains B.

Constraints

$0 \leq A$ , $B \leq 10^9$

Output Format
Output the number of different sequences of getting points by the teams that leads to the final score A : B. Final means that the game should be over after this score is reached. If the number is larger than 10^9+7, output number modulo 10^9 + 7. Print 0 if no such game ends with the given score.

Example input #00

3
25

Example output #00

2925

Example input #01

24
17

Example output #01

0

Comment: Write the number of ways to get score A:B, $F(A,B)$, as a function of $F(A - 1, B)$ and $F(A, B-1)$.  Be careful not to count $F(A - 1, B - 1)$ twice.  If you know what dynamic programming is, you'll know how to compute this recursion in polynomial time instead of the more direct exponential implementation.  Apply modular arithmetic as necessary.  Post your progress for further comment.

Comment: what should we take the initial value??

Comment: I was wrong about having to worry about counting $F(A-1, B-1)$ twice.  But for initial value, how many ways are there to get a score of $F(A,0)$ if $A \le 25$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this as dynamic programming, so I'm assuming this is some kind of programming assignment rather than a simple math assignment, so I am going to be a bit more explicit with the mathematics than I would for a mathematics homework assignment.

Suppose you are at a point where the score is 13 vs 7.  How many ways could you have gotten that score?  Well the previous score was either 12 vs 7 or 13 vs 6.  So $F(13, 7) = F(12, 7) + F(13,6)$.  If you are very insightful you'll realize that you didn't over count anything, but there is another way to get this same result.

If the score is A:B, how many rounds were played? A + B rounds were played.  And the first player won A of them.  So there were ${A + B \choose A}$ ways the rounds could have been won.  We know from a fellow named Pascal who used to carry a triangle around that ${x \choose y} = {x - 1 \choose y} + {x - 1 \choose  y - 1}$.  You can use this relation to also give you a nice recursive solution to your problem.

...but the above is only valid if $A \le 25$ and $B \le 25$, or if $A=B$.  There is no way to get a score like 37:29, so you need to figure out for what cases $F(A,B) = 0$.  Also, for a score like 48:47, there is only 1 valid previous score, so in these cases you'll have a different recursive formula than in the other cases.

With dynamic program you can get a result that is $O(AB)$ for small A,B and $O(A)$ for large A,B.

If you want to go beyond dynamic programming, notice that $F(A,A) \equiv 2F(A - 1, A - 1) \pmod {10^9 + 7}$ for large enough $A$, so you can use modular exponentiation to really speed up your program.